# Can not run on iphone with error have the same architectures (armv7) and can't be in the same fat output file

Tags: ios, compilation, archive

I try to run the app on my iPhone and finally failed.
The only device that I currently have with me has iOS6 installed on it.And the architectures setting is 'armv7'.
It says the following when trying to run the app:

```
CreateUniversalBinary
/Users/tongfei20/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestiPadCal-eywphcxyudcjxhcvayjcldqtcetq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TestiPadCal.app/TestiPadCal
normal "armv6 armv7 armv7"
    cd /Users/tongfei20/Desktop/TestiPadCal
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    lipo -create /Users/tongfei20/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestiPadCal-eywphcxyudcjxhcvayjcldqtcetq/Build/Intermediates/TestiPadCal.build/Debug-iphoneos/TestiPadCal.build/Objects-normal/armv7/TestiPadCal
/Users/tongfei20/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestiPadCal-eywphcxyudcjxhcvayjcldqtcetq/Build/Intermediates/TestiPadCal.build/Debug-iphoneos/TestiPadCal.build/Objects-normal/armv7/TestiPadCal
-output /Users/tongfei20/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestiPadCal-eywphcxyudcjxhcvayjcldqtcetq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TestiPadCal.app/TestiPadCal

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo:
/Users/tongfei20/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestiPadCal-eywphcxyudcjxhcvayjcldqtcetq/Build/Intermediates/TestiPadCal.build/Debug-iphoneos/TestiPadCal.build/Objects-normal/armv7/TestiPadCal
and
/Users/tongfei20/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestiPadCal-eywphcxyudcjxhcvayjcldqtcetq/Build/Intermediates/TestiPadCal.build/Debug-iphoneos/TestiPadCal.build/Objects-normal/armv7/TestiPadCal
have the same architectures (armv7) and can't be in the same fat
output fileCommand
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo
failed with exit code 1
```

But when I instead of  adding the 'armv6 armv7'.It can be archived!It is so strange.
Anyone will be appreciate！